Rear cable length
Park tools says "When determining housing length at the front of the bike, make sure there is enough housing to allow for sufficient rotational travel of the handlebars — about 90 degrees for road bars, and for MTB bars, as far as they will go if interrupted or 180 degrees if uninterrupted."
Why is the requirement different for road vs mtb and interrupted vs uninterrupted? (90° vs 180° vs as far as possible)
Also, so what if the cable is too short? In a crash, I'm already slowing down, so handlebar rotation induced braking doesn't sound like it would hurt me more. Is it just potential damage to the bike components?

Interesting - so Park thinks road bikes (drop bar bikes) could turn 90 degrees to either side (and then the bars hit the top tube)   but flatbar bikes could have turn twice as much, so the wheel is in a fore-aft position again.   Is that how you read it ?    The other way of reading seems overly restrictive on road bikes - I turn more than 45 degrees when doing low speed manoevers.   Or a third option, its just wrong ?

Yeah I read it as road: 180° In total, mtb: 360° in total, which doesn't make sense to me

My gut feeling is it is based around crash survival and damge from cables pulling tight. MTB's crash more often and bars get twisted and turned in all sorts of bad ways. The bike needs to be rideable afterwards. Roadies need to be aerodynamic and there is a culture of 'presentation' that MTBer's don't get.  No one likes a roadie with cables flopping all over the place and they crash far less often.

I don't understand what you mean by "handlebar rotation induced braking" -- the only braking effect that turning the bars can have is your face grinding against the road/trail after losing control of the bike. And yes, you run the risk of breaking your shifters and/or brake levers if the cables are what limit the rotation. Although with lightweight carbon bikes, there may be an argument for sacrificing those components but protecting your top tube from being destroyed by the handlebars smashing into it.

It's oversimplified and really isn't very good advice.
What they say for mountain bikes is the classical guideline for all bikes. Allow for maximum rotation or up to 180 degrees. Otherwise, if the bike falls over etc, the limiting factor of the fork's movement becomes the housing/hose, which can damage it.
If someone says you only need 90 degrees on a road bike, what they're talking about is because of the nature of modern road bikes and especially higher end and/or smaller ones, the housings/hoses can be floppy and look excessive if you do the above, due to short distances between where they usually exit the bars/tape and where the frame ports are. In some cases there can be a functional hit too, when making the housings/hoses long enough to turn the bars 180 degrees causes their entry angle into the ports to be awkward. Tri bikes are big on this. The risk is still there of the same bad things happening that informed the classic advice, only now the consequences of a kinked housing are greater because the systems are less tolerant of them (for shifting) and they take far more time to replace.
Saying this applies equally to all road bikes is irresponsible because it doesn't. When the shift housings don't run under the tape, for example, you really don't lose much by just giving them full movement on most bikes, especially ones with traditionally located housing stops on the down tube.

Ah so if the limiting factor of the fork's movement becomes the housing, then only the housing would get damaged? What about the rider during a crash? That's the most common argument I see online favoring long cables. (sorry I edited my question 5 minutes after you answered. Please read the new section at the bottom)

Braking induced by bar rotation is hard to make happen while in motion unless the length chosen is basically insane, or if you're 9 and you're riding around with the bars spun without realizing it.
